# How to detect parts of unicode in a string in Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, unicode, pymysql

I call an api to get some info, and sometime the response has examples like below.

```
"address": "BOULEVARD DU MÃ\u0089ROU - SN PEÃ\u008fRE,  "
```

How can I detect these and convert them to the latin letters? I want to upload this data to a MYSQL Database. Right now it throws the following warning.

```
Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC2\\x88ME A...' for column 'address' at row 1")
```

I'm using pymysql, to insert this info to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

The example data was original encoded as UTF8, but decoded as `latin1`.  You can reverse the process to fix it, or read it from the source using `utf8` to begin with:

```
>>> s = "BOULEVARD DU MÃ\u0089ROU - SN PEÃ\u008fRE,  "
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'BOULEVARD DU MÉROU - SN PEÏRE,  '
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.encode()` str function:

```
>>> "BOULEVARD DU MÃ\u0089ROU - SN PEÃ\u008fRE,  ".encode("latin-1)
'BOULEVARD DU MÉROU - SN PEÏRE,  '
```

Though be aware if the API response contains any UTF-8 characters that cannot be encoded in "latin-1" then you'll hit a `UnicodeEncodeError`

If at all possible, rather than do this you'll probably want to change the character set of your mysql database to UTF-8

Comment: That's Python 2, right? The OP tagged the question with `python-3.x`, this is pretty relevant here. In Python 3, `str.encode` always returns a byte string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple errors -- "double encoding" and unicode "codepoints".  Hence, it is hard to unravel what things went wrong.

It would be better to go back to the source and fix the encoding at each stage -- not to try to encode/decode after the mess is made.  In almost all cases *no* conversion code is needed if you specify UTF-8 at every stage.

Here are some notes on what to do in Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

The hex for `É` should be `C389` and the hex for `Ï` should be `C38F`.  There should be no `\uxxxx` except in HTML.  Even in HTML, is is normally better to simply use the utf8 encoding since HTML can handle such.